# Write-to-file code doesn't write

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

Well, I am trying to write a line of information to log in a text file (.txt) but this is the part where the code fails to write. Everything else works, except this but doesn't give any errors.

```
public void writeConfig(File config, Boolean append, String errored){
    try {
        Writer output;
        if (config != null){
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(config));
        } else {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(er));
        }
        if (append == true){
            output.append(errored);
        } else {
            output.write(errored);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        try {
            loadErrorLog(error, true, "Failed to write to Boom's Log.\n");
        } catch (Exception e1){
            log.info("Major Malfunction #686 : Tell Maker immediatly.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `append` a `Boolean` and not a `boolean`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not closing the writer, which means all the data is just staying in the buffer.

You should close it in a `finally` block.

Additionally:

- your use of the `append` parameter is distinctly dodgy - you should almost certainly be passing it to the constructor of the `FileWriter` (or `FileOutputStream`). I don't think `append` in `Writer` does what you think it does.
- Try to avoid comparing with `true` - just `if (append)` would have been clearer
- Using the conditional operator could make your `FileWriter` code cleaner, especially if you used it *just* for the file:

  ```
  File file = config == null ? er : config;
  Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
  ```
- I would avoid using `FileWriter` in the first place, as it always uses the platform default encoding. Use a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` instead, specifying the encoding explicitly (e.g. UTF-8)
- Avoid catching `Exception` in most places; here it would be cleaner to just catch `IOException`.
- It looks like your `loadErrorLog` method should probably be doing that logging on failure, otherwise I suspect you'll be writing that block of code *every* time you call it.
- Do you really want to continue if you fail to write the config? Is it definitely *this* method which should handle the exception? I'd potentially remove the `catch` block entirely (leaving just a `try`/`finally`) and let the `IOException` bubble up the stack

Comment: Do I need to output.flush() first?

Comment: @KeirDavis: I wouldn't - closing is meant to flush anyway. I believe there are some odd error cases where closing after an exception may not flush, but I would *personally* not worry about that.

Comment: +1 The only note about `if (append)` is that append is `Boolean` for some reason and could be `null` I would suggest making append a `boolean`